# SVG: right-align text at the end of a textPath

Tags: html, svg

I'd like to right-lign text at the end of a textPath:

```
<svg height="300" width="400">
    <defs>
        <path id="myTextPath" d="M30,160  A175,175 0 0,1 370,160" />
    </defs>
    <path d="M30,160  A175,175 0 0,1 370,160" style="stroke: black; stroke-width:1; fill:none;" />
    <g fill="black" stroke="none">
        <text x="0%" y="0" text-anchor="start">
            <textPath xlink:href="#myTextPath">Start</textPath>
        </text>
        <text x="50%" y="0" text-anchor="middle">
            <textPath xlink:href="#myTextPath">Middle</textPath>
        </text>
        <text x="100%" y="0" text-anchor="end">
            <textPath xlink:href="#myTextPath">End</textPath>
        </text>
    </g>
</svg>
```

You can see this working here: http://jsfiddle.net/7sqdxw11/

The **Start** text begins right where I'd expect - at the beginning of the textPath.

However, the **end** text ends well short of the end of the textPath.

(The **Middle** is also well shy of the middle of the textPath).

Here's a screenshot:

[image]

What am I doing wrong? How to I get the **End** to end at the right end of the textPath arc?

Answer (score 4):

In SVG percentage coordinates generally refer to the either the width of the SVG, or in some cases the width of the parent object.

So in your example the "100%" will result in a value of 400px - the width of your SVG.  However your path actually has a length of 466.  You can get the length by experimentation, or by using some Javascript:

```
var len = document.getElementById("myTextPath").getTotalLength();
```

So if you change the "100%" to "466" you get the effect you wanted.

```html
<svg height="300" width="400">
    <defs>
        <path id="myTextPath" d="M30,160  A175,175 0 0,1 370,160" />
    </defs>
    <path d="M30,160  A175,175 0 0,1 370,160" style="stroke: black; stroke-width:1; fill:none;" />
    <g fill="black" stroke="none">
        <text x="0" y="0" text-anchor="start">
            <textPath xlink:href="#myTextPath">Start</textPath>
        </text>
        <text x="233" y="0" text-anchor="middle">
            <textPath xlink:href="#myTextPath">Middle</textPath>
        </text>
        <text x="466" y="0" text-anchor="end">
            <textPath xlink:href="#myTextPath">End</textPath>
        </text>
    </g>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use the `<text x="...` attribute. Use `startOffset` (along with `text-anchor`) on `<textPath>` instead:

```html
<svg height="300" width="400">
    <defs>
        <path id="myTextPath" d="M30,160  A175,175 0 0,1 370,160" />
    </defs>
    <path d="M30,160  A175,175 0 0,1 370,160" style="stroke: black; stroke-width:1; fill:none;" />
    <g fill="black" stroke="none">
        <text>
            <textPath xlink:href="#myTextPath">Start</textPath>
        </text>
        <text>
            <textPath xlink:href="#myTextPath" startOffset="50%" text-anchor="middle">Middle</textPath>
        </text>
        <text>
            <textPath xlink:href="#myTextPath" startOffset="100%" text-anchor="end">End</textPath>
        </text>
    </g>
</svg>
```